# Catch the output python script using Jython

Tags: jython-2.7

When I input a Python script, e.g. `2 + 2`, it returns `4`. That is what I want. But when I try to input `print 'hello world!'`, an exception occurs! I just want to get the interpreter's output from the executed Python script.

```java
private PythonInterpreter coder = new PythonInterpreter();
private String script;
private PyObject interp;

private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      

    try
    {
        coder.exec(script);             // this will execute the python script
        interp = coder.eval(script);    // this is what i use in trying to catch the interpreter's output
        System.out.println(interp);     // and trying to see what it returns
    }

    catch(Exception s)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, s, script, WIDTH, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception? Note that if you are working against Python version 3, you need `print('hello world!')` instead (`print` is now a function).

Comment: I stored it in a string variable, but i got this problem about printing, i think it does not return any value, it just print it in the system

Comment: I get a syntax error when trying this: `SyntaxError: no viable alternative at input 'PythonInterpreter'`. What is the except you get? You still haven't posted that. Please edit the answer to include it.